# Как сократить CSS селекторы в PhpStorm?

Tags: css, phpstorm

Использую YUI Compressor для минификации CSS файлов, но в нем нет функции сокращения CSS селекторов (возможно она есть, но не знаю пока как ее использовать). Поделитесь опытом каким плагином или инструментом можно решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Пример ниже:

```
было:
html body div.clearfix.main-area div.container div.row.main-content div.col-md-3 div.ca-hover div.carousel-content h3

стало:
.carousel-content h3
```

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что CSS селекторы из вашего "_было_" и "_стало_" совсем не эквивалентны?

Comment: Отвечать вопросом на вопрос - оригинально. Если вам нечего сказать, лучше промолчать. Не будем тратить время зря.

Answer (score 1):

Такой функции нигде нет и не будет. Потому что селекторы разные.

Если надо, сам пиши плагин для гранта или галпа.

Comment: Понятно, но все же не теряю надежду. Буду искать.